# how to pass a decimal value using number type Edittext in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to pass a decimal number (edtNumber) to a Toast but when i running the app the number doesn't appear in the Toast.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView txtDate;
    private Button addBtn;
    private EditText edtNumber;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtDate = findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
        addBtn = findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
        edtNumber = findViewById(R.id.edtNumber);
        String weight = edtNumber.getText().toString();

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("'Date\n'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        String currentDateAndTime = sdf.format(new Date());
        txtDate.setText(currentDateAndTime);


        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Weight:"+ weight + "\n" + currentDateAndTime, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please take a 2 minute tour of the site over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problem

---

The problem is in this line:

```
String weight = edtNumber.getText().toString();
```

you care calling that line of code as soon as the activity is created where it has no value. You want to get value only if the button is clicked.

#### Solution

---

You will have to add this line to your `onClick` method. Finally, the code will look like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView txtDate;
    private Button addBtn;
    private EditText edtNumber;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtDate = findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
        addBtn = findViewById(R.id.addBtn);
        edtNumber = findViewById(R.id.edtNumber);
        String weight = "";

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("'Date\n'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        String currentDateAndTime = sdf.format(new Date());
        txtDate.setText(currentDateAndTime);


        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                weight = edtNumber.getText().toString()
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Weight:"+ weight + "\n" + currentDateAndTime, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution was right but i had to transform the variable into an array like this:
`final String[] weight = {""};`